# How to catch ''unable to instantiate application" errors?

Tags: android, crash-dumps

We recently encountered an error on Android API 28 devices:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.my.company, PID:
>   18245 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.my.company.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.my.company.MainApplication" on path: ...

We found the issue was due to a missing entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library for more details).

Now the higher-ups want us to get alerted when we encounter issues like this (including a crash dump), however I have been unable to find a way to do this, since adding exception handling libraries like Crashlytics or ACRA won't work because the app is never initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Google is doing this automatically and the results are viewable in the Google Play Console in the "ANRs & crashes" section:
[image]
[image]

Then in the "NOTIFICATION SETTINGS" I can set it to notify when a crash/ANR occurs.

However it also appears that the error in the OP about the missing entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file is not being reported, so back to the drawing board on that one.